# Linux opengl es 2.0 from windows

Tags: c, linux, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have few graphic effects on image which i am able to run on windows 7 visual studios 2008 with opengl es 2.0. on ARM Emulator.

Now i want the to port my implementation to linux for embedded devices. I dont have any idea on linux and never worked on it till now.

Is it possible that someone can provide a primer or some material so that i can start my porting for windows to embedded linux.

Secondly, Is it the same code which i just need to copy from windows to linux?

I want to install Ubuntu in my system and try to run the project in ubuntu with Linux Opengl es 2.0 Emulator[Emulator for linux](http://www.malideveloper.com/opengl-es-20-emulator.php) from Eclipse.

Kindly  help me if i am in the right path for porting my code from windows to Linux

Thank you

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I read few blogs and found out that the windows emulator and linux emulator differ in the egl frame work.
So now i want to use Imagination Technologies Windows emulator [link(http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdk/KhronosOpenGLES2xSGX.asp)
without EGL framework and replace all egl functions with self defined functions in c. Is it possible that i can find any help one to make this framework instead of using EGL APLs [link](http://www.khronos.org/egl)
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to have a fully compatible OpenGL ES 2.0 (1.0/1.1 as well if required) environment is to use one of the GPU manufacters' SDK.

One of the most common and well done is the one from Imagination technologies for their PowerVR GPU line (Iphones and a lot of Androids http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PowerVR_products)

You can download and then install the emulator and the SDK from this link:

http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/

Another solution to your request, which is my preferred one, is to not use the emulator, study the differences between the ES world and the standard OpenGL libraries and write your code to run smoothly (with the due exceptions and differences) on both worlds.

In this way, you will have, at the end of the efforts, a fully operational code on both universes (Mobile and Desktop). Two birds with a stone.

This is the way I have followed for my PATRIA 3D Engine development.

Cheers
Maurizio

Comment: I need to work on es. my question was regarding the porting of project from windows to linux.
I figured it out. that its portable except for the gluing functions which i dont need 

Thank you :) your answer help me